# LazySeq cannot be cast to Comparable on sort-by

Tags: clojure

`clojure 1.9.0`

A simple test of `sort-by` on the character array works below,

```
user=> (sort-by identity [[\B] [\a]])
([\B] [\a])
```

but why did another test fail to `sort-by` case-insensitively?

```
user=> (sort-by (partial map #(Character/toLowerCase %)) [[\B] [\a]])

java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

**Solution**

Using [mapv](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) instead of [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) makes it.

```
user=> (instance? clojure.lang.LazySeq (map identity []))
true
user=> (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentVector (mapv identity (map identity [])))
true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but why did another test fail to sort-by case-insensitively?

`map` returns a lazy sequence, which doesn't implement `Comparable`. `mapv` works because vectors support `Comparable` and that's what [`sort-by` is using](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/841fa60b41bc74367fb16ec65d025ea5bde7a617/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java#L144) to sort.

```
(supers (type []))
=> #{... java.lang.Comparable ...}

(supers clojure.lang.LazySeq)
=> #{clojure.lang.IObj clojure.lang.ISeq clojure.lang.Seqable clojure.lang.IMeta java.lang.Iterable java.util.List clojure.lang.IHashEq java.lang.Object clojure.lang.Obj java.util.Collection clojure.lang.IPending clojure.lang.Sequential clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection java.io.Serializable}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need map:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str] ))

(sort-by  #(.toLowerCase  (str/join %)) [[\a \b] [\B] [\a]])
;=> ([\a] [\a \b] [\B])
```